# Running shell script to launch mongod on startup but before login on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, 18.04, scripts, startup

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox. I am trying to run a shell script that launches multiple mongo instances. I want the script to run after the system reboots but before login

I have added the following line in my `/etc/profile` file -

```
/bin/sh /home/dimension/data/scripts/run_mongo_instance.sh
```

The shell script has the following permissions

```
dimension:~$ ls -lh data/scripts/run_mongo_instance.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 313 Oct  4 17:30 data/scripts/run_mongo_instance.sh
```

Here are the contents of the file -

```
nohup mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/archive/archive.conf &

# ReplicaSet

nohup mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/replica/replica2.conf &

nohup mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/replica/replica1.conf &
```

I am able to run this file manually by running the following command -

```
sudo /bin/sh /home/dimension/data/scripts/run_mongo_instance.sh
[sudo] password for dimension: 
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

Corresponding output -

```
dimension:~$ ps -ef|grep mongo 
mongodb    953     1  2 10:01 ?        00:00:30 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
root      3614  2441  1 10:03 pts/0    00:00:20 mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/archive/archive.conf
root      3615  2441  1 10:03 pts/0    00:00:22 mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/replica/replica2.conf
root      3616  2441  2 10:03 pts/0    00:00:27 mongod --config /home/dimension/data/config/replica/replica1.conf
dimensi+  6145  6119  0 10:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. On 16.04 the command was used to run inside `/etc/rc.local`

How should I make this script work on 18.04?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: Do you want the script to run after boot but before login? Or do you want the script to run when you login to the booted system?

Comment: See the duplicate question, which also applies for you. You can continue to use /etc/rc.local, but first you need to turn the systemd service "rc-local", that "activates" the rc.local file, on.